# How to set latitude/longitude from bundle to Google Maps

Tags: android, maps, bundle

I'm trying to bundle form main_activity to google_maps_activity. The bundle contains a string and the string contains an float with coordinates, latitude and longitude.

I think my bundle is fine, but when i open my app it opens Google Maps with the default coordinates (0, 0). Any suggestions on what i can do? Or do differently?

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
      mMap = googleMap;

      Intent map_aktivitet = getIntent();

      Bundle bundle = map_aktivitet.getExtras();

      String sett_longitude = bundle.getString("longitude");
      float sett_longitude2 = bundle.getFloat(sett_longitude);

      String sett_latitude = bundle.getString("latitude");
      float sett_latitude2 = bundle.getFloat(sett_latitude);

      String name = bundle.getString("textViewName");



      LatLng home = new LatLng(sett_latitude2, sett_longitude2);
      mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).title("Here lives " + name));
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(home, 16));
       }
```

Comment: what are string and float receiving ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String sett_longitude = bundle.getString("longitude");
float sett_longitude2 = bundle.getFloat(sett_longitude);

String sett_latitude = bundle.getString("latitude");
float sett_latitude2 = bundle.getFloat(sett_latitude);
```

this is completely wrong...

try this

```
String sett_longitude = bundle.getString("longitude");
float sett_longitude2 = Float.parseFloat(sett_longitude);

String sett_latitude = bundle.getString("latitude");
float sett_latitude2 = Float.parseFloat(sett_latitude);
```

Comment: Shit man! I just saw that horrible mistake...(!) Thank you very much.

Comment: @naSSa happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double` to parse `marker`, `marker` accept `double` :,

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap;

  String sett_longitude = getIntent().getStringExtra("longitude");
  double sett_longitude2 = Double.parseDouble(sett_longitude);

  String sett_latitude = getIntent().getStringExtra("latitude");
  double sett_latitude2 = Double.parseDouble(sett_latitude);

  String name = bundle.getString("textViewName");

  LatLng home = new LatLng(sett_latitude2, sett_longitude2);
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home).title("Here lives " + name));
  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(home, 16));
   }
```